# How do I make polynom compatible with the align environment?

Tags: align, polynom

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{polynom, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv{x}{x+1} % OK

\begin{equation}
   \polylongdiv{x}{x+1} % OK
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
   \polylongdiv{x}{x+1} & % compilation error
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The package polynom is incompatible with the align environment of amsmath. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I think I just stumbled upon a workaround.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{polynom, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \text{$\polylongdiv{x}{x+1}$} & \\ % works
    \mbox{\polylongdiv(x)(x+1)} & % mangled formatting
\end{align}

\end{document}
```